# I keep getting a 403 error with Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm using Django OAuth toolkit to restrict access to API and I've followed [this tutorial](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application), but for some reason, DOT is restricting access to every request I make on it.

`urls.py`:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from rest_framework import routers
    from api import views

    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    admin.autodiscover()

    from rest_framework import generics, permissions, serializers

    from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
        url(r'^api/v1/carfax/$', views.GetCarFax.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='list'),
        url(r'^api/v1/get_carfax/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', views.GetCarFax.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='retrieve'),
        url(r'^api/v1/carfax/create/$', views.PostCarFax.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name='create'),
        url('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
    ]
```

views.py:

```
class GetCarFax(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ''' This view will be used for POSTing new carfax reports to the database '''

    queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarFaxSerializer
    # authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope]
    #print('TEST')
    # lookup_field = "vin"


    def list(self, request):

        # accessed at url: ^api/v1/carfax/$
        queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
        serializer = CarFaxSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # accessed at url: ^api/v1/retrieve/{pk}/$
        queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
        record = get_list_or_404(queryset, vin__exact=pk)
        serializer = CarFaxSerializer(record, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

class PostCarFax(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarFaxSerializer
```

My `requests` file:

```
 headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer *****'
    }

    data = {
        "vin": test[0],
        "structural_damage": test[2],
        "total_loss": test[1],
        "accident": test[5],
        "airbags": 'TESTTTTT',
        "odometer": test[4],
        "recalls": test[6]
    }

    data = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/carfax/create/', data=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    print(response.status_code)
    return response
```

`get-token.py`:

```
def authorize():

    client_id = '***'
    client_secret = '***'


    data = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'test1',
        'password': 'test1',
    }


    response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/o/token/', data=data, auth=(client_id, client_secret))

    return response.text
```

I'm not sure exactly where I am going wrong here, the requests work when I remove the authentication. But otherwise it always throws a 403 forbidden error. I am getting the token successfully, the 403 error is basically telling me that my token doesn't grant me those permissions

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial by chance?

Comment: Sure here you go https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application